# Android: Refresh Activity

Tags: android

I have a problem !
I have 3 Activities, DB, and WebServer. Let say that every 20 min server clean my DB and fill it up with new Data. Every Activity use data from DB. How to refresh active activity automaticaly when new refresh of DB was done. Thanks.

Comment: are you asking how to inform the application that DB update is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend sending a Broadcast each time the DB is updated and registering broadcastreceivers in each activity that needs to be informed of the update.

EDIT example:

In your DB-class, send this broadcast:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my.db.updated");
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In the Activities where you need to be informed of DB-changes:

```
public void onCreate(...) {
  ...

  BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReciever() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      if(intent.getAction.equals("my.db.updated") {
        // Do something
      }
    }
  };

  registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("my.db.updated"));
}
```

Comment: I thought about that..But also  I thought that maybe somebody know an easier way...Thanks

Comment: But how to know what Broadcast to start ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can push the new data. Take a look at timers and divide your activity like this onCreate -> init -> getData

and then put getData(); within a timer

Good luck